# Unreachable statement for if statement

Tags: android

I am getting an error of unreachable statement error at "if (paramint==2)" in this code.

```
for (;;)
    {
        return super.onCreateDialog(paramInt);
        if (paramInt == 2)
        {
            final Dialog localDialog2 = new Dialog(this);
            localDialog2.setContentView(R.layout.multiautotext);
            localDialog2.setTitle("setcontact");
```

Comment: can you post complete code

Comment: That's because you `return` from the method before this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the method/function even before the comparison is happening.

Check line number 3

```
return super.onCreateDialog(paramInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

after executing return statement it will never go into if statement.

```
for (;;)
{

    if (paramInt == 2)
    {
        final Dialog localDialog2 = new Dialog(this);
        localDialog2.setContentView(R.layout.multiautotext);
        localDialog2.setTitle("setcontact");
        return super.onCreateDialog(paramInt);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java after return nothing will work, return always last statement.

```
for (Your loop Condition)
    {
        if (paramInt == 2)
        {
            final Dialog localDialog2 = new Dialog(this);
            localDialog2.setContentView(R.layout.multiautotext);
            localDialog2.setTitle("setcontact");
            return super.onCreateDialog(paramInt);
          }
}
```